# Shanka Abhisheka

Tags: puja

I heard Shanka Abhishekam should not be performed to Lakshmi. I am looking for more details on why, and also for any other god/goddess, we should not do Shanka Abhishekam.

Any scriptural references, some reliable sources would be good; if not, personal views/knowledge as well.

Thank you.